# Is there similar to strace and tcpdump toools for Xorg?

Tags: debugging, window, xorg, sniffer

I'm looking for debug tools for X.

Something like **tcpdump** or **strace** for X protocol. To debug X windows.

You can read my another question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25182216/xterm-randomly-hangs-while-scrolling-in-vim-inside-screen

Answer (score 1):

[xtruss](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/xtruss/), [xtrace](http://xtrace.alioth.debian.org/) and [xmon](http://linux.maruhn.com/sec/xmon.html). Wireshark also has a good x11 dissector.
All of them have good core protocol support but may lack some extensions. Also note that most of GL calls are serialized using it's own protocol inside glxRender request body when using indirect opengl, and direct gl completely bypasses x11 after allocation of screen buffer using DRI extension.

Comment: I'm currently read about wireshark here http://xwindow.angelfire.com/page23.html, looks like such information must be in wiki http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strace